# Find element by CSS selector AFTER certain element with Selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I'm looking to get the text "Interesting" which is the first occurrence of the class `b` after `h1.important`.
How would I do that in Selenium?

```html
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">Not interesting</div>
</div>
<div class="title">
    <h1 class="important">Title</h1>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">Interesting</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to find "Interesting" using a fancy selector or xpath?
This would also match the first element: `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".b").text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".b")
```

this will return a `list` in **Python-Selenium bindings**.  so you cannot do `.text` on it.

Instead try to use `driver.find_element` like below :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.title+div>.b").text
```

in case you want to use xpath, try this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='title']/following-sibling::div/div").text
```

Note that, `CSS_SELECTOR` is preferred over `xpath` in **Selenium automation.**

Answer (score 1):

This XPath

```
//h1[@class='important']/../following-sibling::*//*[@class='b']
```

Should give you the next `b` class occurrence after the `h1.important` node as you asking

Answer (score 1):

This xpath should work

`(//h1[@class="important"]/following::*[@class='b'])[1]`